# $\Delta f = 0$, $f(x) = \phi(r)$. Must $\phi'(r)>0$?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I'm reading Folland PDE and Corollary 2.3 says if $f(x)=\phi(r)$ is radial on $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $\Delta f=0$ on $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$ iff $\phi(r)=a+br^{2-n}$ for $n\neq 2$ and $\phi(r)=a+b\log r$ for $n=2$.

In the proof he uses the radial form of the Laplacian and immediately says
$$
\frac{\phi''(r)}{\phi'(r)}= \frac{1-n}{r}
$$
to arrive at the conclusion. But what if $\phi'(r) = 0$ somewhere? Is there some reason why this doesn't happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have the book, but since $\Delta f=(r^{n-1}\phi'(r))'/r^{n-1}$ then clearly it is $0$ iff $r^{n-1}\phi'(r)=cst$, which gives the formula for $\phi$.

Comment: Did you mean $\Delta f$, not $\Delta \phi$?

Comment: I know $\Delta f = \phi''(r) + \frac{n-1}{r}\phi'(r)$.

Comment: Ahh I see the RHS = $\frac{1}{r^{n-1}}(r^{n-1} \phi'(r))'$ by the product rule.